# Accordion Bootstrap table with spacebars

Tags: mongodb, meteor, bootstrap-4, spacebars

I have seen questions pertaining to accordion but not entirely to my specific need. My table is populated using spacebars, more specific a nested each loop like this:

```html
<tbody>
{{#each piece in pieces}}
    <tr id="{{piece._id}}" class="itemList table-warning">
        <th class="name tText">{{piece.name}} {{piece._id}}</th>
        <td class="pdf tText" style="text-align: center"><a class ="pdf" href="{{piece.pdf}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        <td class="audio tText" style="text-align: center"><a class="audio" href="{{piece.audio}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-volume-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
        <td class="format tText">{{piece.instrumentation}}</td>
        <th class="price tText" >${{piece.price}}</th>
        <td><input class ="qty" type ="number" name ="quantity" value="0" min="0"></td>
    </tr>
<!-- Row that is being clicked-->
    <tr class="partsList">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <th class="partName tText">{{piece.name}} Parts</th>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    {{#each part in piece.parts}}
<!-- Rows that should accordion -->
<!-- Currently ALL rows accordion on click. Need to accordion based on _id-->
        <tr class="partList">
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td class="pname tText">{{piece.name}}: {{part.pname}}</td>
            <td class="price tText">${{part.pprice}}</td>
            <td><input class="qty" type="number" name="quantity" value="0" min="0"></td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I have a click function like so:

```js
'click .partsList': function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.partList').nextUntil('tr.itemList').toggle();
}
```

The accordion function works, however it works with every instance of the each loop. i.e. every `tr class ="partsList"` will accordion at the same time on click.

To my understanding of the each loop, I can access the _id of a document using `{{piece._id}}`. If I set the table row id to equal that however, it only reads the `_id` of the FIRST document in the collection.

What I need is on click for the `<tr class="partList">` to accordion based on `_id`. Or perhaps you would go about this a different way than bootstrap tables?

Please let me know if my question needs clarification.

Comment: Can you please add some `<!-- html comments -->`  in your code about which part of the code is clicked and which part is then collapsed? It makes it more clear to see the involved elements to the intended functionality.

Comment: I edited as you suggested

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the clicked `.partslist` using a `data-*` attribute. This causes jQuery to select only this specific items. Note that you need to attach the `data-*` attribute to the row that is clicked and to the rows that should collapse:

```html
<tbody>
{{#each piece in pieces}}
    ...
    <!-- Row that is being clicked-->
    <!-- use the _id value of the piece context as data attribute -->
    <tr class="partsList" data-id="{{piece._id}}"> 
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <th class="partName tText">{{piece.name}} Parts</th>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    {{#each part in piece.parts}}
    <!-- Rows that should accordion -->
    <!-- Currently ALL rows accordion on click. Need to accordion based on _id-->
    <!-- use the _id value of the piece context as data attribute -->
    <tr class="partList" data-target="{{piece._id}}">
    ...
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
</tbody>
```

```js
  'click .partsList': function(e, templateInstance){
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the data-id attribute of the clicked row
    const targetId = templateInstance.$(e.currentTarget).data('id')
    // skip if this row is not intended to toggle
    if (!targetId) return
    // toggle based on data-target attribute
    templateInstance.$(`.partList[data-target="${targetId}"]`).nextUntil('tr.itemList').toggle();
  }
```

Comment: `data-id` reads properly and cycles through the ids however `data-target` still only reads the first `_id` of the document.
Is there something else I need to do to access the `data-id` within the second each loop? not sure if it matters or not

Comment: I am not sure if I understood what you aim for. Which loop do you refer to - `{{#each piece in pieces}}` or `{{#each part in piece.parts}}`

Comment: sorry, within the `{{#each part in piece.parts}}` loop the `data-target` will only read the id for the first document in the collection

Comment: And you want each `part` to be triggered by another `piece` than the one in the current loop?

Comment: no, each `part` should be within a `piece` and I only want 1 set of `part` to accordion rather than all of them. Does that make sense? So in plain english if I click "Piece 1" then I want only "Parts of Piece 1" to collapse, not "Parts of Piece 1" & "Parts of Piece 2"

Comment: There are two factors that could be the issue here: either the `nextUntil` messes with the querySelector, so you may try to remove the `.nextUntil('tr.itemList')` call to see if that works or there is an issue with the _id values of the pieces. Do they really have all a different `_id`?

Comment: They do, in fact I checked the dom elements and they read correctly but when I try to get the `_id` using js, it reads incorrectly. Will try removing `nextUntil` and see if that does anything